# How to make RecyclerView inside CardView and CardView have it's size when it has low items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `CardView` but i have problem that i have 2 buttons in bottom of the `RecyclerView` so i put them at the end of `RelativeLayout` and give them `parent_bottom` true so i can make them visible but that makes the `CardView` have the full screen whether the `RecyclerView` have items of not.

### Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Your active inspections"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/btnClear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="CLear" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Like this]

And when i tried another thing the code below to make them below the `RecyclerView` so it fixed in case and the other case like shown (Buttons at the bottom not shown)

So how to fix this ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Your active inspections"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="CLear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Buttons at the bottom not shown]

the target one is this and when items expands it fit only the screen and don't go out of it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you can solve by changing your `relativelayout` inside `CardView` to `LinearLayout` and create nested relativelayouts for buttons. In order to avoid the nested layouts try my below code will help you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text=" Your active inspections"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="CLear" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/bb_darkBackgroundColor" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Adjust recylerview top and bottom margin according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the Recyclerview weight = 1 that means the parent should be LinearLayout 
please check the code below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"            >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text=" Your active inspections"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
             />

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="CLear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_normal" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `RelativeLayout` inside the `CardView` with `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Below Code. It's working Perfectly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Your active inspections"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_below="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="CLear" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_normal"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Continue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvActiveInspections"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activeInspections"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: it works on when it has a lot of items but when don't have so many it still at the bottom

Comment: You want to show button show the bottom of the recycle view. Like When show 1 item show bottom off the one item?